# Descending sequence of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V_1\supsetneq V_2\supsetneq\cdots$ be a strictly decreasing sequence of (infinite dimensional) vector spaces over a field. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $U_n\subset V_n$ be a complement of $V_{n+1}$, $V_n=U_n\oplus V_{n+1}$.

**Questions**

1. Is it true that
   $$
   V_n=\bigoplus_{m=n}^\infty U_m\bigoplus U_\infty
   $$
   for a subspace $U_\infty\subset V_1$ independent of $n$?
2. If the answer to 1. is generally no, is there a special choice of $U_n$ to make the statement valid?
3. If the answer to 1. or 2. is yes, is it true that
   $$
   U_\infty=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n?
   $$
4. If the answer to both 1. and 2. is no, how could I find a (Hamel) basis $\{e_i\}_{i\in I_1}$ of $V_1$ indexed by a set $I_1$, and a decreasing series $I_1\supsetneq I_2\supsetneq...$ of subsets such that $\{e_i\}_{i\in I_n}$ is a basis for $V_n$? Is such a thing possible in general?

   Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V=L^2$ the set of all sequences $\{ a_i \}$ such that $\sum a_i^2$ converges. Let $V_n$ be the subspace defined by $a_0=a_1=\cdots=a_n=0$. $\bigcap V_n=0$. $V$ has no countable basis.

Comment: I am afraid this answers all four. Negatively. I will think more before deciding.

Comment: All right, thanks.

Comment: I am glad that it helps.